# Access data cube generated by Microsoft MSSQL BI

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, ssas, business-intelligence

I am working on a project where I am hoping to use Microsoft MSSQL Business Intelligence to create data cubes, then access the processed data like browsing them in the BI studio, except the access is via JDBC. So basically I'd like to treat the data cubes as regular tables. Is that doable? If so could someone give me a pointer on where to start? (I am new with the BI process but I am pretty good with RDBMS & SQL). Thanks.

Ken

Answer (score 2):

This might be of help to you ?

http://www.matthewgodding.com/articles/2010/2/27/getting-data-from-sql-analysis-services-using-java-and-olap4.html

Google is your friend.....

Comment: Very interesting - thanks for the link, Nick. However, from the article it seems I need to execute the MDX ad-hoc. My problem is since I have a really large set of data (100s of millions records), running ad-hoc MDX will not be an option as the user experience will be terrible. I was hoping there's a solution where I can run the MDX on a scheduler, dump the data to a staging table, then access it via JDBC. Sorry if I wasn't clear on that perspective.